# Discord OAuth2 login Fail via Android Webview

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, android-webview, discord

I'm using discord to let the user login on my android app.
The code is as follows:

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/webview_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MyActivity">
    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/authWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

DiscordOAuth.java:

```
package com.example.oauth2test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

class DiscordOAuth {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Discord OAuth 2 Login";


    public void getAuthentication(Activity activity) {

        String authURL = "https://discordapp.com/login";

        WebView authWebView = activity.findViewById(R.id.authWebView);
        authWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript
        authWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        authWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        authWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        authWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        authWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        authWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        authWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        authWebView.loadUrl(authURL);
        authWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

when the above is executed, you will get a login page, but when you try to loging, the loading animation will appear for a moment, and you will be back on the login page without even a success or a failure

after searching, i suspect that the problem has something to do with multiple windows and how to deal with them, but i can't be sure.

The final goal is to use oauth2 via a WebView to login to discord and get the username of the user

Answer (score 1):

Implement `AuthCallback` interface in your class & you will get response in callback methods

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Do you mean [**This Interface**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/class-use/Callback.html). How do i use it. Can i even use javax in android..... can you please give a breaf example......please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Discord internally needs WSS connection to complete authorization. WSS connection requires DOM storage to store client information. However in Android webview, DOM storage is disabled by default. you can change this in WebSettings by `webSettings.domStorageEnabled = true`